# If $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 0$ is zero, why does it not work with L'hospital's way?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, infinity

I just got a simple question regarding the use of L'Hopitals method for finding limits. Usually L'Hopitals method can be used to find limits like 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{d}{dx} \sin x}{\dfrac{d}{dx} x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\cos x$$

Here if we plug $0$, we can find the limit of the original function $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ at $0$ using the $\cos x$ function. Put $0$ in, and you will get $1$, which is correct. However, if we replace $x$ with $\infty$, we don't get the right limit.

$$\cos x$$
$$\cos(\infty)$$

Which is not right for the limit of the original function, as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 0$$ Using the new function which we get via L'Hopital's method does not help get that. Is this like a special case? In what cases could then L'Hopital's way not work?

Comment: Why do you think that L'Hospital's rule works for $x \to \infty$?

Comment: $\sin x$ has no limit as $x \to \infty$ (and also does not approach either $\infty$ or $-\infty$) so the limit is not in one of the valid indeterminate forms for applying l'Hopital.

Comment: @Somos Because [it is proven it works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form)

Comment: @Peyton I have read the Wikipedia article more carefully and indeed the point $c$ can be infinity, but there are other requirements as well on the limits of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: The main issue with L'Hospital's Rule is that most often one does not pay attention to all the hypotheses under which it works. Perhaps the rule is thought as a *thumb rule of differentiate and plug* instead of a genuine mathematical theorem. One of the hypotheses of the rule is that the limit of the $f'/g'$ (expression obtained after differentiation of numerator and denominator) should have a limit (finitely or infinitely).

Comment: @DanielSchepler: contrary to what many believe the rule applies to form $0/0$ and "$\text{anything} /\infty $" and the second form is not well known. Thus whether $\sin x$ has a limit or not is immaterial. One needs to see that denominator tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @Somos: the case $x\to\infty$ can be easily converted into $t\to 0^{+}$ via substitution $x=1/t$ so that is not a problem here.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh, Yes, you can transform the problem, but now you are not using L'Hospital on the original problem.

Comment: @Somos : you should have checked the substitution and applied L'Hospital's Rule on the resulting expression. Once you do that you will at once recognize that the substitution proved that the rule is applicable when $x\to\infty$. Note that applying L'Hospital's Rule on $f(1/t)/g(1/t)$ yields the ratio $\dfrac{f'(1/t)(-t^{-2})}{g'(1/t)(-t^{-2})}=f'(x) /g'(x) $. So the rule holds if $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Peyton : From your link: "If either $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x) = 0$ or $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} |f(x)| = \lim_{x \rightarrow c} |g(x)| = \infty$ ..." does not apply.  Neither $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sin (x)$ nor $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} |\sin (x)|$ exist.

Comment: L'Hôpital only applies when your limit is either $\dfrac00$ or $\dfrac{∞}{∞}$.

Comment: To use L'Hopital for the limit at $0$ of $(\sin x)/x$ you need to know that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$. That fact is usually proved using the limit you are trying to evaluate, so your argument is circular, not correct (unless you have some other way to find the derivative of $\sin$).

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Your statement is false.  L'Hospital's Rule applies to $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac{\text{ANYTHING}}{\infty}$, even if the limit of the denominator fails to exist.

Comment: @EricTowers L'Hospital's Rule applies to $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac{\text{ANYTHING}}{\infty}$, even if the limit of the denominator fails to exist.  Or were you suggesting something else?

Answer (score 4):

L'Hopital has the form if $A,$ then $B.$ It doesn't say $A$ iff $B.$ Thus the limit of $f/g$ can equal $L$ (B) even if the limit of $f'/g'$ doesn't exist.

Incidentally, L'Hopital works in cases of $\text { ? }/\infty.$ In other words, if $\lim g(x) = \infty$ and $\lim f'(x)/g'(x) = L,$ then $\lim f(x)/g(x) = L.$

Answer (score 1):

L'Hospital's Rule has a lot of hypotheses.  You seem to be ignoring the hypotheses on the limits of the numerator and denominator of the original ratio.  Let's check a statement of the Rule.

From *Calculus: Early Transcendentals, 4th ed.* by Rogawski, Adams, Franzosa (p. 250):

> Assume $f$ and $g$ are differentiable in an interval $(b,\infty)$ and that $g'(x) \neq 0$ for $x > b$.  If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)$ exist and either both are zero or both are infinite, then $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$ provided that the limit on the right exists.  A similar result holds for $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

(This quote contains an astoundingly common error.  As Rogawski explains on p. 72, infinite limits do not exist.  A better phrasing of the second sentence is "If it is the case that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)$ both exist and are zero or it is the case that both limits are infinite [which in Rogawski includes either sign], then ...".  This error is common among those who have studied real analysis because in that setting one works in the extended reals, so $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are points in the working set of numbers and can be the *value* of a limit.  In (just) the reals, this is not the case.)

Applying this to your example, $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = x$.  While it is the case that
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x = 0  \text{,}  $$
we find that
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sin x $$
does not exist.  (The sine function takes every interval $(b,\infty)$ to $[-1,1]$, so the limit fails to exist.  One can arrive at the same conclusion by studying $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \sin(1/x)$, but with the added advantage that the graph fits on a finite piece of paper.)

So, no, your example is not a special case.  L'Hospital's Rule already constrains to which limit expressions it can be applied, excluding the example you give.

Comment: In fact, L'Hospital's Rule applies to $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac{\text{ANYTHING}}{\infty}$, even if the limit of the denominator fails to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compute the limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as $x \to \infty$, which is 0 and not an indeterminate form - this, L'Hopital's doesn't apply.

Comment: Just because you can calculate the limit in another way doesn't automatically mean l'Hopital doesn't apply.  e.g. you can calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x}$ easily enough without l'Hopital, but l'Hopital also works on it.

Comment: L'Hopital can be applied whenever the denominator $\to \infty.$

Comment: @zhw. How do you figure? By OP's example, this should be false.

Comment: By "can be applied" I mean that if $g\to \infty,$ and if $f'/g'\to L,$ then $f/g\to L.$

Comment: @zhw. : Then your comment is not an improvement of this Answer in the context of the Question.  $f'/g' = \cos(x)$ does not have a limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$.  For careful statements of L'Hopital's Rule, your first comment ignores necessary hypotheses on the existence of various limits, claiming, for instance, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x \sin x}{x}$ exists, which is false (although your second comment does correct for this particular example).

Comment: @EricTowers Evidently, you don't seem to understand the conditions for which LHR applies.  The indeterminate form $\frac{\text{ANYTHING}}{\infty}$ can work.  In your example, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x}$ qualifies since the denomiator tends to infinity.  BUT that is not the only condition.  Note that the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x)+x\cos(x)}{1}$ fails to exist.  And it is for this latter reason that LHR fails.  One needs $\lim\frac{f'}{g'}$ to exist.  Here it does not.

Comment: @MarkViola : $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x \sin x}{x}$ does not exist.  Plot it.  For any $N > 0$, there is an $x_1 > N$ such that $x_1 \sin(x_1) / x_1 = 1$ and an $x_{-1} > N$ such that $x_{-1} \sin(x_{-1})/x_{-1} = -1$.  The expression in this limit (where it is defined) oscillates with amplitude $1$ all the way out to $\infty$, so does not have a limit.  (Not being defined somewhere in every neighborhood of infinity *also* obstructs the existence of the limit.)

Comment: @EricTowers So what?  Read the answer.   I never said that the limit exists!